# How to access a control form from a constructor in another class

Tags: c#, controls, constructor

C# question:
I have a textBox in a default form Form1 and I want to access (write on) it from a constructor in another class that is in another different file. How can I do it?

Tx in advance,
Gerard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a property in the `Form1` class that exposes the textbox or its `Text` property, then pass an instance of the `Form1` class to the constructor.  (Or as a `static` proeprty)

Comment: I like the static option, since constructor param would defocus from the feature I want to emphasize: Constructor overloading ;-).
Tx SLacks

Comment: Well static seemed a good alternative but it raises an Error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.richTextBox1'". Any clue?

Comment: You need to make a static property of type `Form1`, then access the property.  For example, if your property is on the `Form1` class and is named `Instance`, you would write `Form1.Instance.richTextBox1`.  Make sure to make it public.

Comment: oops did you tried out? When declare the in the class Form1 the property:
        public static Form1 frm {
            get {
                return frm;
            }
            set {
                frm = value;
            }
        }

In my class I can't access the controls like you mentioned Form1.frm.richTextBox1, no richTextBox1 or other controls from the form are accessible.

What am I missing!?

Tx onde more.

Comment: I tried no make the richTextBox1 public (I think I was missing it) but now I get a runtime error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in myapp.exe" 
Can you help?

Comment: *sorry I meant to write "I tried TO make the richTextBox1 public"

Comment: Got it
Just declared a "private static Form1 frm = null" and redefined the Property to public static Form1 Frm { get { return frm; } set { frm = value; } } and most important and the source off all problems I initialized the frm = this in the Form1 construtor.

Tx anyway.